# Folders named as the current month by command line

Tags: script, windows-server-2008

I have this code :

```
xcopy  "C:\30*.zip"  "C:\Folder\"
```

what i want is to copy the zip files to a new folder, this folder named as the current month

```
ex : March , April
```

Comment: I don't think xcopy supports that. You should try powershell.

Comment: PowerShell supports xcopy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a clunky way of doing it in powershell:

```
$a = "C:\Folder\"
$a +=get-date -format MMMM
xcopy "c:\30*.zip" $a /I
```

Comment: Thank you so much @soandos, but he ask me :
    "Does C:\New Folder\New Folder\December specify a file name or     directory name on the target (F = file, D = directory)?" 
how to skip this?

Comment: because i want to add it to schedule task

Comment: added /I. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

For another command script way to do this, using [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html), simply use [the `%_MONTHF` implicit environment varable](http://jpsoft.com./help/_monthf.htm) and the ordinary [`copy` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/copy.htm).  It's a one-liner:

```
copy /MD C:\30*.zip C:\Folder\%_MONTHF\
```

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003,2007). [*Performing some commonly desired tasks with JP Software's command interpreters.*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/common-tasks-with-jpsoft-clis.html). Frequently Given Answers.