# Folders named as the current month by command line

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Folders named as the current month by command line](https://superuser.com/questions/371430/folders-named-as-the-current-month-by-command-line)

I have this code :

```
 xcopy  "C:\30*.zip"  "C:\Folder\"
```

what i want is to copy the zip files to a new folder, this folder named as the current month

> > ex : March , April

I'm using Windows Server2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the month as

@For /F "tokens=2,3,4 delims=/ " %%A in ('Date /t') do @(

Set Month=%%A

Set Day=%%B

Set Year=%%C
)
@echo Month = %Month%

But remember this depends on the regional date format.

Then you can create folder

MD Month
.
and copy the zip in the new Month folder created